# in React.ts why a component is re-rendered only when I click outside of the browser and then click back inside the webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, state, react-select

Using react-select components when I change the value of the selected option the value is changed and displayed in the UI but when I reset the form and return the select components to their original state (stored in a separate state to preserve original state without re-fetching the data from DB).

The select components are re-rendered only when I click anywhere outside the webpage and then click inside the webpage.

anyone seen such behavior and can explain?
thanks.

```
   {applicationsPerLocation ? (
                        
                        <DefaultLocationWrapper>
                            <DefLocationSettingsHeader />
                            <DefLocationSettingsTitles />
                            
                            {applicationsPerLocation.map((location: AppsByLocationsType, idx: number) => (
                                <DefaultApplicationPerLocationItem
                                    key={idx}
                                    location={location}
                                    DisplayProfileData={DisplayProfileData}
                                    returnFunction={onSelectDefaultApp}
                                    idx={idx}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </DefaultLocationWrapper>
                    ) : (
                        <LabelWrapper>No Apps Found.</LabelWrapper>
                    )}
```